# Created a function to rename PDF files in a folder based on a matching file name in Excel, how to execute?

Tags: python, excel, rename

I have the below code, the folder to where it contains the Excel file with two columns (Original Name of the PDF file, and New Name desired column called "Matched Results.xls"; as well as all of the original name PDF files that are contained in this folder. How do I run this code so that all of my PDFs will be renamed?

```
def rename_file(file_to_rename, source_file):
    p = Path(file_to_rename)
    filename = p.stem
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(r'C:\\Users\Chris Lee\\Desktop\\File_Rename_Python\\Matched_Results.xls')
# excel file to get new filename????
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

for row_num in range(sheet.nrows):
    row_value = sheet.row_values(row_num)
    col = 2 # 'john smith' col number
    if row_value[col] == filename:
        new_filename = f'{row_value[col+1]}'  # format as you want
        p.rename(Path(p.parent, new_filename + p.suffix))  # rename
        break

def get_paths_in_directory(directory):
    return Path(directory).glob('*.pdf')

if __name__ == "__main__":

source_file = r'C:\\Users\Chris Lee\\Desktop\\File_Rename_Python\\Matched_Results.xlsx' # excel file to get new filename
source_directory = r'C:\\Users\Chris Lee\\Desktop\\File_Rename_Python' # directory where your files to rename are.

# iterate all pdf files in the given directory
paths = get_paths_in_directory(source_directory)
for file_to_rename in paths:
    rename_file(str(file_to_rename), source_file)
```

Comment: 1. Fix your indentation - python expects 4 white space characters for every block - defs, for loops, ifs, elses, whiles, etc. 2. If your code is configured correctly, find the file in your explorer, open up a shell there and type `python name_of_your_python_script.py`, and hit enter.

Comment: Hi Shmack - I am using Jupyter notebook, what new cell should I create and execute? What would I type in the next cell and run?

Comment: Oh, hey no big deal this time, but it'd be helpful for in the future to include a detail like that - not that it makes a huge difference, but it may in the future. I will post a formatted version of your code as an answer - I can't guarantee that in of itself that it will work. I am making the assumption that the logic is all there. and then I will show you how to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

The point of  `if __name__ == "__main__":` is to check if the code was run directly and not imported. Since that you are not importing:

```
def rename_file(file_to_rename, source_file):
    p = Path(file_to_rename)
    filename = p.stem
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(r'C:\\Users\Chris Lee\\Desktop\\File_Rename_Python\\Matched_Results.xls')
    # wb should be the below variable instead
    #wb = xlrd.open_workbook(source_file)
    
    # excel file to get new filename????
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

    for row_num in range(sheet.nrows):
        row_value = sheet.row_values(row_num)
        col = 2 # 'john smith' col number
        if row_value[col] == filename:
            new_filename = f'{row_value[col+1]}'  # format as you want
            p.rename(Path(p.parent, new_filename + p.suffix))  # rename
            print("the if was matched!", new_filename, Path(p.parent, new_filename + p.suffix))
            break

def get_paths_in_directory(directory):
    return Path(directory).glob('*.pdf')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    source_file = r'C:\\Users\Chris Lee\\Desktop\\File_Rename_Python\\Matched_Results.xlsx' # excel file to get new filename
    source_directory = r'C:\\Users\Chris Lee\\Desktop\\File_Rename_Python' # directory where your files to rename are.

    # iterate all pdf files in the given directory
    paths = get_paths_in_directory(source_directory)
    for file_to_rename in paths:
        rename_file(str(file_to_rename), source_file)
```

You can replace everything after and including `if __name__ == "__main__":` with:

```
def my_func():

    source_file = r'C:\\Users\Chris Lee\\Desktop\\File_Rename_Python\\Matched_Results.xlsx' # excel file to get new filename
    source_directory = r'C:\\Users\Chris Lee\\Desktop\\File_Rename_Python' # directory where your files to rename are.

    # iterate all pdf files in the given directory
    paths = get_paths_in_directory(source_directory)
    for file_to_rename in paths:
        rename_file(str(file_to_rename), source_file)
```

and call the function with:

```
my_func()
```

so your whole jupyter field would look like:

```
def rename_file(file_to_rename, source_file):
    p = Path(file_to_rename)
    filename = p.stem
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(r'C:\\Users\Chris Lee\\Desktop\\File_Rename_Python\\Matched_Results.xls')
    # excel file to get new filename????
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

    for row_num in range(sheet.nrows):
        row_value = sheet.row_values(row_num)
        col = 3 # 'john smith' col number
        if row_value[col] == filename:
            new_filename = f'{row_value[col+1]}'  # format as you want
            p.rename(Path(p.parent, new_filename + p.suffix))  # rename
            print("the if was matched!", new_filename, Path(p.parent, new_filename + p.suffix))
            break

def get_paths_in_directory(directory):
    return Path(directory).glob('*.pdf')

def my_func():

    source_file = r'C:\\Users\Chris Lee\\Desktop\\File_Rename_Python\\Matched_Results.xlsx' # excel file to get new filename
    source_directory = r'C:\\Users\Chris Lee\\Desktop\\File_Rename_Python' # directory where your files to rename are.

    # iterate all pdf files in the given directory
    paths = get_paths_in_directory(source_directory)
    for file_to_rename in paths:
        rename_file(str(file_to_rename), source_file)


my_func()
```

provided you have all the needed imports.

EDIT: A function I put together with some threads on SO - you will need to figure out how you want to rename your file, create the algorithm, then implement it in the `if` statement.

```
import os

def rename_func(directory):
    d = os.fsencode(directory)

    for file in os.listdir(d):
        filename = os.fsdecode(file)
        if filename.endswith(".pdf"): 
            # this is what your file will be renamed to
            os.rename(os.path.join(d, filename), 'renamed_file.pdf')

rename_func(r"C:\my_dir")
```

Comment: I've ran the my_func() but I don't see the files being renamed, maybe I am missing something? Again thanks for your help on this

Comment: Yah - I mean, like I said, I am operating on the assumption that the logic was right. You're going to have to put some print statements in to make sure that the output is what you're expecting and play with it - I think I see something that might be part of the problem, so I will update my post.

Comment: Okay, give that a try - it'll print out if it found any matches and the path to them, if any. Wait, updated wrong place. Okay, good to try.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I wish I could show the source files:
 best_match_score Name Final Name

My final name desired is column 4

Comment: okay, so then we need to change the column index - probably to 3 because most indexes are 0 based. So I changed that to reflect that in the code, but you can also change it in your notebook and rerun it. It was originally `col = 2` for reference - changed to `col = 3`

Comment: No, not yet. I am thinking something to do with the file path, maybe I'll try to run a simple code to rename one file or something first in that same path

Comment: yah, I was hoping that `print("the if was matched!", new_filename, Path(p.parent, new_filename + p.suffix))` would contain enough information if it output anything.

Comment: I did find a workaround, it appears we can actually just use the command line, and use the "rename old filename new filename", was working hard for nothing :)

Comment: Woah, woah, woah, woah - from the looks of the code, it parses an excel sheet for the new names of the files in a list of files. I mean you could rename them manually, but why when would you presumably have far more than a few?

Comment: Yeah, I agree I wish there was a way to do it without using the command line manually. Is there a way to do it using the import os module?

Something similar to this but using looping: import os
os.rename(r'file path\OLD file name.file type',r'file path\NEW file name.file type')

Comment: Posted an edit.